# Why can I still navigate out of my home directory when using vsftpd with winscp?

Tags: ftp

System: Linux Ubuntu 10.04

I have set up a vsftpd server and everythings seems to work fine if you log in over a browser, but if I log in using winscp then I can navigate out of my own home directory which is avtually restricted by the config file (below)

Does anyone know why this would happen? I need to be sure that noone can rumage around on my server looking at files.

Here is my VSFTPD config file:

```
listen=YES 
anonymous_enable=NO 
local_enable=YES 
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES 
use_localtime=YES 
xferlog_enable=YES 
connect_from_port_20=YES 
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list 
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty 
pam_service_name=vsftpd 
chroot_local_user=NO 
chroot_list_enable=YES
```

Comment: Here is my config file VSFTPD config file:
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES

Answer (score 3):

[`vsftpd`](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) is a [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP) server, but you're using [`WinSCP`](http://winscp.net/), which is a [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) client (a file copying protocol over [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)). These are two totally different services so you can configure `vsftpd` all you want, it won't impress your WinSCP ;-) To actually access your server via FTP, you need an FTP client.

Comment: WinSCP supports FTP too.

Comment: I stand corrected by the WinSCP author. So the issue was that OP connected using SFTP mode instead of FTP mode and thus got a different behaviour than he expected.

Answer (score 0):

Set `chroot_local_user` to `YES`.
After this the `chroot_list_file` will be a list of users *not* to lock into their home directories, so disable it unless you have such users as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. 
The way out of this was firstly to understand that ftp is not sftp as DarkDust said. I Found that by using Filezilla which uses FTP and not SFTP everything works as expected. But I didn´t realise that if you use the same login with an sftp server you can navigate to wherever you want. 
MY solution was to add "denyuser username" in the /etc/ssh/ config file which restrict sftp access to the server. The only way in is then only FTP which works as the VSFTPD server configuration should!

Thanks again,

Rob